# How to update the color of section title without uitableview reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using willDisplayHeaderView to change the color of section title:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    header.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

Now, I want to update the color of a section title, how to do it without `[tableview reloadData]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two method in `UITalbeView` to get the headerView and footerView respectively:

```
- (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)headerViewForSection:(NSInteger)section NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)footerViewForSection:(NSInteger)section NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

Try this:

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = [self.tableView headerViewForSection:0];
header.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```